# How to stop autostart of an installed program?

Tags: autostart, huawei

I installed a certain software according to the following instruction set.

## Begin

--How to Install----------------------
* You need login as root *

1. Run "tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2"
2. Run "./install" in TERMINAL to install MobilePartner
   eg: # bash //install
3. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.
4. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct
5. Finish installing

--How to run--------------------------
* From shortcut in desktop

- Run MobilePartner in your install path
  eg: # //MobilePartner
- Plug in your device, it will run automatically

## End

Now, whenever I plug the dongle the software is autorun. Can you explain me how to stop this autorunning.

Comment: what is the output of `ls /etc/udev/rules.d/` ?

Comment: 50-Huawei-Datacard.rules
70-persistent-net.rules
70-persistent-cd.rules
 README

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the additional data from your comment I suggest to leave the script there but to deactivate it this way:

`sudo chmod -x /etc/udev/rules.d/50-Huawei-Datacard.rules`

Usually this should be enough to prevent an autostart.

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant by "I suggest to leave the script there but.."?

Comment: @PasanW this command only prevent the script from being activated by udev, without deleting it, it's a suggestion, maybe you will need it in the future.